# GAE standard でカスタムドメインを追加したい

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

Google Domainsで購入したドメインをカスタムドメインに追加したく、「新しいドメインの追加」画面で購入ドメインを選択したところ、

> {購入ドメイン}は、既にプロジェクトにマッピングされています。
>   www.{購入ドメイン}は、既にプロジェクトにマッピングされています。

と表示されマッピング保存ができませんでした。
実は、以前削除した古いプロジェクトに今回のドメインを登録した経緯があったので、
そことの関係？を断ち切ったあとでないと、新しいプロジェクトにカスタムドメインを登録できないと考えているのですが、
具体的な方法がわからず、ご教授くださいmm